# try to set data in function inside the array it will error

Tags: java, arrays, sudoku

I write this code for solving Sudoku game and when I try to set data in function inside the array it will error, here is the code:

```
 public static boolean  CheckRowColumnBox(int data,int b,int[][] matrix,int r,int c){

     if(CheckRow( data, r, matrix ) 
     && CheckColumn(data, c, matrix) 
     && CheckBox(data, b, matrix,r,c)) {

        matrix[r][c]==data; //error here
        return true;
      }
        return false;
      }
```

> why??? how can I solve it, 
>   where i can define r and c

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: post the stack trace ?

Comment: the error in r and c  in matrix     it is function in bug code

Comment: Did you want `=` instead of `==`?

Answer (score 0):

Change `matrix[r][c]==data; //error trigger here` to `matrix[r][c]=data; //no error here`. Else put the first in a if statement block.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java